# How do I replace std::binary_function with something else without pain?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, deprecated, legacy-code

We are currently using some 3rd party packages which use some std::binary_function, std::unary_function deep inside. As you might know, these functions had been deprecated in C++14, and now they all have been removed from C++17. We are going to use some new features of C++17 and simultaneously we are not going to make some major changes since it might lead to some instability in our codes. How do we simply replace these legacy C++ features(std::binary_function,...) with something else with lesser pain.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: what about `std::function` ? Can you show some code to demonstrate your "pain"? I can think of problems while replacing `std::binary_function` with `std::function`, though it is not clear what problems you are facing

Comment: @user463035818: `std::function` is a very "heavy" class with lots of functionality, and member data. `std::binary_function` only has a few typedefs.

Comment: "... they all have been removed from C++17" -- as in, they **are no longer required** in C++17. Standard library implementors typically continue to provide them, precisely because of this sort of problem. As long as your standard library provides them, you don't need to change anything. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any existing types in standard library, but it's not a big deal to create your own:

```
template<class Arg1, class Arg2, class Result> 
struct binary_function
{
    using first_argument_type = Arg1;
    using second_argument_type = Arg2;
    using result_type = Result;
};

template <typename ArgumentType, typename ResultType>
struct unary_function
{
    using argument_type = ArgumentType;
    using result_type = ResultType;
};
```

Both of these classes are just simple base classes for user-defined functional objects, e.g.:

```
struct MyFuncObj : std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    bool operator()(int arg) { ... }
};
```

Having aliases for arguments allowed to use some standard library built in functionality, e.g. `std::not1`: `std::not1(MyFuncObj())`.

My guess why this was deprecated is because after C++11 mostly lambdas are used to create functional objects. And having variadic templates it's quite easy to create generic version of `not` and other things without having `std::not1`, `std::not2`.